# Inheritance in datacontracts

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a class say `supplierAddress` which comes from a webservice (it is a datacontact). I then have a second class `myAddress` which inherits from that class and has a few more constructors and metods.

What I want to do is pass a `myAddress` back to the webservice. When I pass a cast down myAddress it throws seriazation errors, which makes sence as its a refrence object and the whole object is still being passed even if im casting down.

Is it possible to clone just the base class of an object? Is what im trying to do possible/correct ?

Comment: Ps. Exact errors avalible on request. I didnt include it because i dont think its relevent.

Comment: In general if you have an error during serialization/deserialization error message could contains all information that you need to fix this issue. For example, you could turn on tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and in appropriate log file you'll see all necessary details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify [Known types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751512.aspx) for your base class.

UPDATE: additional clarification.

SOA (Service-Oriented Architecture) paradigm doesn't support such common features like polymorphism or method overloading. This behaviour based on very simple fact: you don't know which platform will consume your service. Its definitely possible to consume your service in platform or language that doesn't support such thing like inheritance or method overloading.

That's why you should create your service functions with unique names and that's why you should explicitly stated what types you're going to pass instead of base class reference.

When you specify known types this information would expose out of your service through metadata and every client could understand how to deal with your responses.